# Amplify Tutorial (Expo) and got error message on signin

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm doing this tutorial: https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/auth/q/integration/react-native#create-login-ui

I followed it completely and did everything they told me to do. The Todo works, but when I added Auth, and wrapped it. The project will start. Users can create accounts. But when you try to sign in on iOS it won't work. Strangely, when I tested it on web, users could sign in. Leading me to think it is a problem with iOS. I tested it on my iPhone with expo installed and it failed there too.

Here is a link to my issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8113#issuecomment-830995508

This is my app.js

````
import config from './aws-exports'
Amplify.configure(config)
import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native'

import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
  View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button
} from 'react-native'

import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify'
import { createTodo } from './graphql/mutations'
import { listTodos } from './graphql/queries'

const initialState = { name: '', description: '' }

const App = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(initialState)
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTodos()
  }, [])

  function setInput(key, value) {
    setFormState({ ...formState, [key]: value })
  }

  async function fetchTodos() {
    try {
      const todoData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTodos))
      const todos = todoData.data.listTodos.items
      setTodos(todos)
    } catch (err) { console.log('error fetching todos') }
  }

  async function addTodo() {
    try {
      const todo = { ...formState }
      setTodos([...todos, todo])
      setFormState(initialState)
      await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(createTodo, {input: todo}))
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error creating todo:', err)
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={val => setInput('name', val)}
        style={styles.input}
        value={formState.name}
        placeholder="Name"
      />
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={val => setInput('description', val)}
        style={styles.input}
        value={formState.description}
        placeholder="Description"
      />
      <Button title="Create Todo" onPress={addTodo} />
      {
        todos.map((todo, index) => (
          <View key={todo.id ? todo.id : index} style={styles.todo}>
            <Text style={styles.todoName}>{todo.name}</Text>
            <Text>{todo.description}</Text>
          </View>
        ))
      }
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', padding: 20 },
  todo: {  marginBottom: 15 },
  input: { height: 50, backgroundColor: '#ddd', marginBottom: 10, padding: 8 },
  todoName: { fontSize: 18 }
})

export default withAuthenticator(App)```

I feel like the problem might be with the ./aws-exports potentially. There was a bug where you had to move it out of src, etc. Anyone have any ideas?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wt6J.png
````

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the login error was due to a bug with expo deprecating a file. See this issue for more. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8113#issuecomment-830995508